# Difficulty updating minimist with Angular 9

Tags: angular, npm, angular9, minimist

I've been doing an Angular 9 project for some time now. A while back, a warning popped up about a moderate security vulnarability with the [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) package. However, when I try to fix them with `(sudo) npm audit fix`, it can't fix these issues, and `(sudo) npm update` won't update them either, even though they have newer versions. How can I fix this?

You can reproduce this problem with a brand new Angular 9 application; minimist is installed by default. For a new project, they will show up as a 'low' level vulnerability, but I think the gist of it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you can't fix it, because angular 9 is not compatible with (new) minimist version, which do not have vulerabilities. You can follow the issues on github:

https://github.com/substack/minimist/issues/145

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36104

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found those when I asked the question.

Comment: karma is dependent on optimist@0.6.1, which has nobody currently supporting it.

Answer (score 3):

This is great question. I do this to fix the vulnerability issue.

Add this in package.json like last entry after devDependencies;

```
"resolutions": {
        "minimist": "^1.2.5"
 }
```

and in scripts section add:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"`
  }
```

when you finish run this in your terminal:

`npx npm-force-resolutions && npm install`

But when installing a new package it usually go back to the previous version and I run the previous command again.